# AngularJS ng-repeat and controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I using simple syntax to show, hide element in ng-repeat

```
<div ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="vm.showItem()">
    {{item}}
    <span ng-show="show">test</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When i was using scope everythink worked fine

```
 $scope.showItem = function(){
   this.show=!this.show; 
 }
```

But same code with controllerAs doesn't work

```
 vm = this; 
 vm.showItem = function(){
    this.show=!this.show;
 }
```

How can i access to show property of current item in ng-repeat?

Controller as http://plnkr.co/edit/Dbp5fO9OEpV6lFRySYUK?p=preview

$scope http://plnkr.co/edit/ptuySNRXSrA64K1IAng3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the current `this` instance from the html like

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="vm.showItem(this)">
```

And use it in your controller

```
vm.showItem = function(_this){
   _this.show=!_this.show;
}
```

The problem you faced is the change of `this` context

Updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/pkxI68sGMXonDOA49EUq?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

### Proof of concept:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', function() {
  vm = this;
  vm.items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) vm.items.push({
    value: i,
    show: false,
    showItem: function() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="item.showItem()">
        {{item.value}}
        <span ng-show="item.show">test</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Than we are going to improve it by extracting `showItem` method to the `Item` prototype

### Second step - using prototype to less memory consume

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainController', function() {
  vm = this;
  vm.items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) vm.items.push(new Item(i));

  function Item(value) {
    this.value = value
    this.show = false
  }

  Item.prototype.showItem = function() {
    this.show = !this.show
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="item.showItem()">
        {{item.value}}
        <span ng-show="item.show">test</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Next step will be extracting `Item` to angular factory

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `vm.show = !vm.show;`

```
vm = this; 
 vm.showItem = function(){
    vm.show=!vm.show;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function definition with.

```
vm.show = !vm.show;
```

I have attached the sample code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


        app.controller('MainController', function () {
            vm = this;
            vm.items = [];
            vm.start = 0;
            vm.end = 20;
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) vm.items.push(i);
            // return vm;
            vm = this;
            vm.show = true;
            vm.showItem = function () {
                vm.show = !vm.show;
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller='MainController as vm'>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items" ng-click="vm.showItem()">
                    {{item}}
                    <span ng-show="vm.show">test</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```